# jquery accordion api css navigation overlay

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

I am having an issue with my navigation menu showing under the jquery accordion widget.
Sorry I can't attach a picture yet but basically the dropdown menu shows underneath the jquery widget.

Here is my css for the navigation menu, I am using the standard jquery ui for accordion.

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 950px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu li.nolink {
        height: 28px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

        font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    /* font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold; */
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}


/* Links */

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

        font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/* font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
*/
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    background: #1f2024;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with it?

Comment: Here is a link to the issue. [link](http://i1319.photobucket.com/albums/t661/slc712/menuaccordion_zps9881db81.jpg)

Comment: Ah, I see. Problems like that are no fun. Perhaps it can be resolved by setting `position: relative` in the `.menu` class? It's difficult to judge without seeing all the code. Can you put together a JSFiddle?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/mAmYS/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `.menu` class:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAmYS/5/)